# Remove or Hide "Select this location" from GMSPlacePickerViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-places-api, google-maps-sdk-ios

How to remove "Select this location" in GMSPlacePickerViewController, integrated using Google Maps in iOS,  [Image For Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6IJG.jpg)